# Why can't closing votes be countered right away?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

I know I can vote to reopen a question that's been judged inappropriate by others.

What I don't understand is why I have to wait for five closing votes to express my disagreement with it? Why can't I add in my vote to keep the question open as soon as one closing vote has been registered?

Comment: You can express your disagreement in the comments. Explain why you think a question should not be closed.

Comment: @bluefeet True that, but these aren't accounted for.

Comment: You can also find the post in the close review queue and vote to leave open there. But really, discuss in the comments or ask for clarification on Meta. Rarely does a question that deserves to stay open get closed or stay closed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the tip on the review queue, I'll look it up.

Comment: @Crono, *these aren't accounted for*. Maybe the question should legitimately be closed, then.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm sorry, this came out wrong (english isn't my main language). What I meant is that a comment is not a *direct* counter for a closing vote. As in, it won't make `closingVotes -= 1`.

Comment: Ah, indeed I thought your comments were being ignored instead :)

Comment: The 'Leave open' vote isn't going to make it `closingVotes -= 1` *either*. It's only a vote to kick it out of the review queue again. If the post attracts direct attention, and deserves to be closed, you are not going to stop it with a 'Leave open' vote or a comment.

Comment: @Crono, not an answer, but in the current state of the system I believe your best bet is to edit the question into shape right away, if possible. I routinely revoke my close votes if the question becomes valid before it is closed, and others probably do the same.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi "I routinely revoke my close votes if..." But does everyone check?  If I vote to close a bad question, sometimes I'll check later to see if they've cleaned it up, but not always (and I'm trying to limit how much time I spend on SO).  Does editing a post automatically send a notification to anyone who has voted to close?  If it does, great--I'm not familiar with all the mechanics of SO--but if not, it seems possible that editing may not help.

Comment: Please note that [the question that `gnat` already pointed to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close) is tagged as `status-completed`. This is [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/213957).

Comment: I would like to be able to do this too.

Comment: I got downvoted at least 3 times for asking this same question when the one shown here was not presented to me as something similar during posted.  Oops.  I want this feature and am adding my vote to this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this paragraph in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/206447) summarizes it nicely:

> Requiring that "silent majority" to go around casting "unclose" votes wouldn't do anything but create more work within the system **for the benefit of a few edge-cases** and **a rather larger increase in the ability for griefers to waste the time of those already going out of their way to review and moderate**. It's a tool for creating gridlock, something Stack Overflow in particular doesn't need any more of.

Keep in mind that a question getting reopened is not particularly common - although it does happen quite a lot from a number-of-questions point of view, it's not that common if we look at the percentage of (closed) questions. [citation needed]

Leave a comment instead mentioning why you think the question shouldn't be closed.

If the asker made any clarifications in the comments rather than editing the post (if lack of clarification may have contributed to the close votes), edit the post and include these details (or ask OP to do so).

If the question is already closed (or wait until it's closed), cast a reopen vote.

Comment: I have sometimes found people so quick to pile on to a question they have not bothered to understand that I have had to appeal to a moderator to forcibly reopen it so I could answer.

Comment: I guess I must accept this as the answer even though I don't fully agree with it. IMHO this solves a problem with another problem, at best.

Comment: @matt Dealing with such cases occasionally, or educating / punishing users who vote to close incorrectly seems like better options than allowing users to cancel close votes - the close review queue is already a problem, allowing users to cancel close votes will very likely just make it (much?) worse.

Comment: @Dukeling I agree that the close review queue is a problem. My proposed solution is to abolish it and give hi-rep users the ability to close (or re-open) _immediately_.

Comment: @matt Related - [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865). My solution would be to make asking questions more difficult / have them be reviewed before going public.

Comment: I like it. I wish I believed these "revolutionary" ideas were going anyplace.

Comment: @matt has a point here, and I think the pack mentality of "let's close this new user's first question"--before they've been given at least a little chance to see how they take feedback and being shown where the edit button is--is just bad practice.  Some people do snap back quickly and go *"oh, I see"* and I feel (maybe under a kind of delusion) that I can intuit the subtlety of those who will respond to feedback vs those who won't.  I'm not saying that a "anti-close-vote" is the answer, but maybe there's a differently-shaped way for people with anti-close-vote intent can have an easier time.

Comment: @HostileFork On the other hand, coming into a community and showing a total ignorance of and/or disregard for their rules is not the type of behaviour we should be encouraging. *The whole point* of the close/reopen system is to close questions with significant issues right away and then reopen them if fixed. A close is only a death sentence if you don't address the reasons it was closed (or if the question if fundamentally inappropriate and can not be asked in an acceptable way, in which case there's no point in *not* closing it right away anyway).

Comment: @Dukeling *"the whole point is to close questions with significant issues right away and then reopen them if fixed"* ... a nice theory, I can get behind it.  But [What about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964817/)?  The guy was new and I had a hunch he'd edit from the beginning, and (until this remark) I've not taken it to meta...just poked at it with little useless edits to try and get it reopened.  We've got language barriers and young 'uns who should be watched out for.  So if you're going to say "close and then reopen if fixed" the whole chain of that needs to be working.

Comment: @HostileFork I don't think we should be treating people differently because there are language barriers or because they're young (avoiding big words and fixing language issues where seen is catering to them, but not treating them differently). Bad questions are bad. The question you linked doesn't seem like a good example because there's still so much that can (or should) be clarified. But the occasional false positive is expected. I don't think the system is perfect, but anyone who takes the time to scan through (and, by assumption, understands) the help center should have no problems here.

Comment: @Dukeling I've browsed your links and such and you seem a smart guy, but I think you need to rethink that bit of *"I don't think we should be treating people differently because there are language barriers or because they're young"*.  Not that we should treat people "differently", but that the barriers to entry and the system should treat *everyone* with an *ask questions first, shoot later* attitude in the system.  You never get a second chance to make a first impression, and if you're making AI then think about the proper AI motto: "How may I help you?  Oh, I see!"  Not "Shut up, kid."

Comment: @HostileFork Seems like we're on the same page regarding catering to people but not treating them differently. If closing a question seems equivalent to "shut up", then perhaps that's something to change (more what's displayed than the process IMO). I honestly care more about maintaining high standards than making good impressions on users who seem like they couldn't care less about the rules, but maybe that's just me (but no, that doesn't mean I think we should be mean about it or that we should not at least point these users in the right direction i.t.o what's wrong with their question).

Comment: @Dukeling ["Sinner, there is no such thing.  Beginner, I have learned to sing..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2clJuq9agCc)  Yes, better messages, better experience.  I think it would help if more programmers would sit down and watch their kids ask questions on the site, and say nothing but watch the details.  So Quality, but with a capital Q.